# Tab bar isn't hidden globallly

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In my appdelegate I have the following code under the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 let tabbar = UITabBar.appearance()
 tabbar.hidden = true
```

and this hides the tabbar on the main view controller, however it doesn't on the second one which is connected to the first of course. There is just a black bar where the tabbar was.

Is there something specific I should do on that viewcontrollers page of code? It's odd that it's doing it for the first controller and not the rest.

Visual:

[image: http://gyazo.com/453627f1615d283451f5ef1c029609de]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check Hide Bottom Bar on Push From Storyboard

Programmatically

```
ASNPhoto *chatViewController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"photoStoryBoard"];
chatViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
```

Comment: Have you set to each rootViewController in Tab bar? i tried and it work for me.comment you Global code form didFinishLaunchingWithOptions then try.